# What is "=" sign in bash?

Tags: bash

I wanted to know what this "=" sign means in Bash. I can't find it in references. All I know is it is used to assign value to variables. Am I missing something can anyone point me to the docs?

[image: Code]

Comment: That's got seemingly nothing to do with bash. How did you come to the conclusion it was something bash interprets? I bet the answer to your underlying questions lie that way!

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: I am very very new to Bash so I didn't know that the tool I am trying to integrate with another tool is made in Bash AND Perl. As I am new to these languages they looked similar and I assumed that it was bash because there was no extension .pl with the file name. Stephen pointed it out and directed me to the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s not Bash, it’s Perl, or rather [Pod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod), the markup language used to write Perl documentation (also known as Plain Old Documentation format).

The `=` sign introduces [command paragraphs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod#Command-Paragraph).